Handling large byte arrays in C#
I've a simple ASP.NET Core Web API that processes large size documents (> 10 MB < 50 MB). Basically it reads a document from CRM like Salesforce processes it with Aspose and send the processed documents to multiple destinations like Salesforce, Email etc.
Instead of using byte array I thought of using streams but my question is after I process the document I get an output stream and how can I send a single output stream to multiple systems in parallel? Since streams are single threaded do I need to clone the stream? Cloning will again cause memory issues right? How we can handle large size documents in a memory efficient way and yet I can send to multiple destinations in parallel.

What kind of stream is the output stream?  A FileStream?  A MemoryStream?

how can I send a single output stream to multiple systems in parallel? if you're responsible for writing to those streams that go off to the other systems then just read from your result stream, and write to each one in order

If you're providing a stream and the remote end is responsible for reading from it, you can look at something one making multiple memory streams that share the same buffer. Which approach do you need? Or even, do you need a mixed approach where some smremote systems are reading from you and some you're writing to?

Indeed, a single Stream cannot reasonably be shared by multiple consumers. Making suggestions here would really need a lot more context of how these systems work and what kind of access they need to the data, but a few thoughts off-hand:

in either case: leased memory (think ArrayPool<byte>.Shared)
incremental: some kind of push model (rather than pull), so as the source iterates it pushes some chunk of payload to all consumers in turn, and what they do with it is up to them
all-at-once: some kind of discontinuous chain, maybe ReadOnlySequence<byte>, and have all consumers indicate back when they're done with it, so you can recycle the chunks


I was looking into the Microsoft Recyclable Memory Stream library... do you think that'll be helpful in my case. Only read-only access is required in parallel processing.

@VJAI Steam is not a readonly concept - it inherently has a "position", which a: isn't conceptually shared by parallel readers, and b: isn't thread-safe to access, which means every read operation. A ReadOnlyMemory<byte> or ReadOnlySequence<byte> would make more sense if multiple callers are going to be given the same data, and let the callers worry about their own position - but if you're going to recycle it, you still need to know when all the callers (separately) have finished. Hence my third bullet point. Another option is "ref counted memory"; I use that approach in some key places,

but it isn't something built into the runtime/framework. I keep having that conversation internally, and it is something I'm still leaning on, but you need to be very careful with that approach. It would be ideal here, and I have library level examples, but - and please don't take this the wrong way, I mean this based purely on years (decades) of seeing how people use these things: if you're asking whether RecyclableMemoryStream is OK to share between parallel callers (it isn't), ref-counted pooled memory probably isn't a good fit for you (yet)

@VJAI to be explicit: ReadOnlyMemory<T> can be just a thin wrapper over a potentially-larger (i.e. pooled) array of T. So: you find you need 1383162 bytes, you ask ArrayPool for that as a mini size, it gives you a rounded-up (powers of 2) buffer, you fill that, and create a ROM-T with the actual length. Then finally, give the array back to ArrayPool. For much larger data, ReadOnlySequence<T> stitches together multiple ReadOnlyMemory<T> as a chain, to work around the max array size limitation. Complex area, but very powerful.

Thanks for the replies @Marc. I'm also looking into this github solution https://github.com/BradSmith1985/NonContig which is exactly what im looking for from the usage perspective. The library is not a popular one so Im little worried. Im looking into the code and trying to understand.

@VJAI that looks like either it predates RO-Sequence, or someone didn't know about RO-Sequence. Or, indeed, RecyclableMemoryStream, which also (now) supports RO-Sequence (plus unmanaged memory). Basically, on the surface and without looking beyond the overview: that looks unnecessary.

we are observing high memory usage in our pods and I believe one of the reason could be the large byte arrays. If we can cut down the large byte arrays into smaller ones and pool them.. then create a custom stream on top of the small byte arrays will this help in quick garbage collection?

@VJAI that would be very situational based on how much of the data is "live" (non-collectable), how much of it is due to LOH saturation (the LOH is collected less frequently, because of cost), etc - but yes, it is certainly worth trying - however, you may need to play with the buffer sizes - lots of too-small arrays may also cause problems due to pool starvation, i.e. the pool has a maximum count per segment size: if you (being silly for the example) use 128-byte buffers for a 2GiB payload, you'll exhaust the pool immediately and just start allocating lots more arrays, adding GC work.
